# Port Enable & Disable

Tags: c#

how to Enable and Disable the USB port.
i need to achive that without out use of devcon.exe

Answer (score 1):

1. [How to disable and enable USB port](http://technofriends.in/2008/02/11/how-to-disable-and-re-enable-usb-storage-devices/). This article teaches you on how to mess with the registry in order to do the enabling and disabling, so you just need to [write C# scripts](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-editing-the-windows-registry) for that.